# Linking two files by ID, and then removing data values from one file by referencing the other in Python using DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I don't think this problem is that complex, I'm just dumb and I'm not sure how to word my search.

I have two files, and they are linked by a common ID. One file (FileA), there is an upper year and a lower year listed out in each row. In the other file (FileB), there is a range of years. I don't need the years defined by the interval in FileA in FileB. How do I remove them by referencing a common ID? It needs to be done per each ID group which is adding to the complexity.

> File A:
>
> ID, uyear, lyear
>
> 2341, 2005, 1995
>
> 2341, 2013, 2010

So I don't need the years from 1995 - 2005, and 2010-2013 for the ID 2341 in FileB

> Example FileB:
>
> ID, year, price,
>
> 4321, 1991, 2.45
>
> 4321, 1992, 2.47
>
> 4321, 1993, 3.4
>
> 4321, 1994, 3.4
>
> 4321, 1995, 2.34
>
> 4321, 1996, 2.44
>
> 3214, 1990, 2.33
>
> 3214, 1991, 2.44
>
> 3214, 1992, 2.55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some 2341 references in your file_b example to show that they would be filtered out:

```
import pandas as pd
file_a = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[2341, 2005, 1995],
    [2341, 2013, 2010]],
    columns=["id", "uyear", "year"]
)
file_b = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[4321, 1991, 2.45],
    [4321, 1992, 2.47],
    [4321, 1993, 3.4],
    [4321, 1994, 3.4],
    [4321, 1995, 2.34],
    [4321, 1996, 2.44],
    [2341, 1994, 2.34],
    [2341, 1995, 2.34],
    [2341, 1996, 2.44],
    [3214, 1990, 2.33],
    [3214, 1991, 2.44],
    [3214, 1992, 2.55]],
    columns=["id", "year", "price"]
)
```

Note that we'd expect one of the 2341s to be kept: 2341 for 1994. The other two rows fall into one of the ranges in file_a.

```
remove_indexes = (file_b
    .assign(file_b_index=lambda x: x.index)
    .merge(file_a, on="id", how="left")
    .query("year_x >= year_y and year_x <= uyear")
    .file_b_index)
file_b[~file_b.index.isin(remove_indexes)].reset_index()[["id", "year", "price"]]
```

Yields

```
      id    year    price
0   4321    1991    2.45
1   4321    1992    2.47
2   4321    1993    3.40
3   4321    1994    3.40
4   4321    1995    2.34
5   4321    1996    2.44
6   2341    1994    2.34
7   3214    1990    2.33
8   3214    1991    2.44
9   3214    1992    2.55
```

The basic idea is to determine which indexes from file_b you need removed (because they match on if and fall into at least one range), then remove rows from the original file by index.

Comment: `.query("year_x >= year_y and year_x <= uyear")`

I'm confused on how this line works. I understand the gist, that it's setting the upper and lower limits, but I don't know where year_x and year_y are coming from?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! This works perfectly, thank you so much. I think I can extrapolate this to work for the following step too. :)

Comment: Ah, it looks like I missed the `l` part of `lyear` in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hm it seems like I'm still getting an error for this. I don't know what year_y and year_x are. 

I added another row for file_a: 4321, 1990, 1994. It doesn't exclude 1991 to 1994 like it should.

Comment: Update: I got it to work, I was entering it backwards: file_a: 4321, 1990, 1994. I am trying to get this to work with a larger file, and this is a sample I pulled from it (and I was copying and pasting from here). For some reason when I use my actual .csv file I get the error: 'year_x is not defined'. It's because of the 'lyear' change vs 'year'. I'm not sure what adjustment to make to get the label to work. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: ``.query("lyear <= year & year <= uyear")``

I got it to work. hooray! And I have a "result" file I'm comparing this to and I think it's officially identical.

Comment: No need to guess: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html